# Minimum sub-vector size k with the divide and conquer technique

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Good morning, I have problems to solve:

**You have a vector of size n, you want to find a sub-vector of size m and that the sum of its elements is minimal**

An example of how this works is:
[see example of operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGXWV.jpg)
where the minimum sub-vector is: {1,3,1} with sum 5

I need to analyze this problem both by brute force (sliding windows explained below), and by the technique of divide and conquer. Then I will write a comparative report and explain that with sliding windows it works much better. This paper is for a university project on algorithm comparison. But I need to build it explicitly with D&C.

I have it done as follows, but I have problems with base cases and returning the minimum sum sub-vector.

```
// Function to find the minimum between two numbers
int min(int a, int b) { return (a < b)? a : b; }

// Function to find the minimum between three numbers
int min(int a, int b, int c) { return min(min(a, b), c); }

// Function to find the minimum sum that passes through the center of the vector
int minSumCenter(int v[], int l, int center, int h)
{

    // Elements to the left of the center
    int sum = 0;
    int left_sum = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = center; i >= l; i--)
    {
        sum = sum + v[i];
        if (sum < left_sum)
          left_sum = sum;
    }

    // Elements to the right of centre
    sum = 0;
    int right_sum = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = center+1; i <= h; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + v[i];
        if (sum < right_sum)
          right_sum = sum;
    }

    // Return de los elementos que están tanto a la izquierda como a la derecha
    return left_sum + right_sum;
}

// Minimum sum sub-vector size m, size v is h-l
int subvectorMinDyV(int v[], int l, int h, int m){
   // Base Case 1
   if ((h-l) <= m) {
       int sum = 0;
       for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        sum += v[i];
       return sum;
  // Base Case 2
}else if(m*2-1 <= (h-l)){
       int sum=0;
       int sumMin = INT_MAX;
       for(int i=0; i<(l+h)-m;i++){
           sum=0;
           for(int j=i; j<m; j++)
            sum += v[j];

           if(sum < sumMin)
            sumMin = sum;
       }
       return sumMin;
   }


   int center = (l + h)/2;
   /* Possible cases
      a) minimum sum sub-vector is on the left
      b) minimum sum sub-vector is on the right
      c) minimum sum sub-vector is a in the middle */
   return min(subvectorMinDyV(v, l, center, m),
              subvectorMinDyV(v, center+1, h, m),
              minSumCenter(v, l, center, h));
}

int main(){
   int v[] = {6,10,4,2,14,1};
   int n = sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]);
   int sumMin = subvectorMinDyV(v, 0, n-1, 3);
   cout << "The minimum amount with DyV is: " << sumMin << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `divide-and-conquer` exactly. The sliding window approach, as pointed out by others, is `O(n)`. (You can't do any better, since you need to look at every element at least once.)

The solution you have is close, except that you are recomputing the sums needlessly. This should do the job

```
void subvectorMin(int* v, int n, int m)
{
  if (n < m)
  {            
    std::cout << "Cannot calculate sub-vector m. (m<n)";
    return; // return early
  }

  // compute the sum of first m elements
  int sum = 0;  
  for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
    sum += v[i];

  // assume answer is at position 0
  int pos = 0;
  int min_sum = sum;

  // check if there is a minimum sum somewhere else
  for(int i = m; i < n; ++i)
  {
    sum = sum + v[i] - v[i - m]; // THIS is the sliding window that 
                                 // avoids the sum being recomputed

    // if smaller sum is found, update the position
    if(sum < min_sum)
    { 
        min_sum = sum; 
        pos = i - m + 1;
    }
  }    

  std::cout << "The minimum component sum is: " << min_sum
            << " , subvector: {";
  for(int i = pos; i < pos + m; ++i)
      std::cout << " " << v[i];
  std::cout << " }" <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to do it with the divide and conquer technique in order to break down the big problem into smaller problems:
- first half of the vector: from 0 to center
- second half of the vector: from center+1 to n
- check whether the minimum amount passes through the centre

I have something done [here my code](https://repl.it/repls/AuthenticWearyDemo) and [here an example](https://i.imgur.com/FpJqAd5.jpg), but I can't finish defining the base cases well.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this requirement. When you data overlaps in this way, you will end up having to do additional work at the partition points. Can you explain *why* you must do it this way?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I need to analyze this problem both by brute force (windows sliding explained above), and by the divide and conquer technique. Then I will write a comparison report and explain that with windows sliding it works much better. This work is for a university project on algorithm comparison.
But I need to build it explicitly with D&C.

Comment: Ok. But your question has completely different code than the link in the comment. Edit your question to reflect what is not working for you.

Comment: Could you help me @cigien with this problem? I've already modified the question. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I can help. The constraints seem artificial, and I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Very clearly, in this approach, the same work is being done multiple times. Also, you need to be more specific in what error you are facing. Try and fix the specific issue. If you can't, then keep removing other parts of the code, until you are left only with the problem that you can't solve. Then post a question. Not sure how to be more helpful than this :(

Answer (score 0):

If you observe your example then u will find out that how the array is partitioned.

```
for n = 6, m = 3

v = 6|10|4|2|14|1
    ---------------
p = 0|1 |2|3|4 |5

g1: 0 1 2
g2: 1 2 3 (1 2 sum already calculated)
g3: 2 3 4 (2 3 sum already calculated)
g4: 3 4 5 (3 4 sum already calculated)
```

When you go from left to right after collecting m element u need to do subtract c-m`th position element. where`c` is current position

```
    void subvectorMin(int* v, int n, int m, int p, int sum){

    if (p >= n) {
    return sum;
    }
int tmp = sum - v[p-m]+ v[p];
    return Min(sum, Min(tmp, subvector(v, n, m, p+1, tmp)));
    }

main() {
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) 
sum += v[i];
    subvectorMin(v, n, m, m,sum);
```

Comment: My idea, to convert my algorithm to divide and conquer, would be how I show in this picture: [URL](https://i.imgur.com/FpJqAd5.jpg) I think we should do something like mergeSort. Thank you for responding.

Comment: its sliding window problem. partioned from left to right. why u alwys divide into middle

Comment: Windows Sliding has an efficiency of O(n^2) and I want to achieve with divide and conquer an efficiency of O(n*log(n)).

The approach that I have been able to build is the following [URL](https://repl.it/repls/AuthenticWearyDemo) but I have problems with the base cases.

Thanks

Comment: @Michael sliding window here is O(n) since on every slide of the window we update by adding the new last element of the window and subtracting the former first element of the window in O(1) for a maximum of O(n) iterations.

Comment: I get o(n^2) because I return the subvector next to the sum. I need to do it with divide and conquer, the approach I have so far is this [program](https://repl.it/repls/AuthenticWearyDemo) but it gives me an error in the base cases.